# How to re-engineering design from source code using rational rose

Tags: c++, visual-c++, reverse-engineering, class-diagram, rational-rose

I would like to create class diagram from existing source code using rational rose.

I have VC++ 6 MFC project and I installed Rational Rose Enterprise Edition Version 2003.06.16. Now I would like to re-engineering the project to create design(class diagram) from the source code. Pls help me step-by-step process to do this, I couldn't get a good doc from internet. One who did this already can help me...

Comment: Just curious, what was missing from the docs generated by .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple. You create a new project, add a component (represents your app), specify the source files in the properties, click Reverse Engineer and Presto: A tangled mess. Then you start dragging things around, moving related groups to different views, etc.

I will caution you that you may be disappointed with the model you get. Apart from the MFC components (which you will want to tuck away so they don't clutter your model), you may find that most of the app is a bunch of unrelated classes. At least that's what I usually found.

Here's a [Rational Rose C++ tutorial](http://www.math.yorku.ca/~cysneiro/ITEC2010/Rose-demo98.doc) [DOC] that should get you started.